# i cant find the min value(which is>0) in each row in selected columns df[df[col]>0]

Tags: python, pandas

this is my data and i want to find the **min** value of selected columns(**a,b,c,d**) in each row then calculate the difference between that and **dd**. I need to ignore 0 in rows, I mean in the first row i need to find 8

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` and all column `['a','b','c','d']` convert to [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) then replace `0` with `+inf` and find `min`. At the end compute diff min with colmun `'dd'`.

```
import numpy  as np
df['min_dd'] = df.apply(lambda row: min(pd.Series(row[['a','b','c','d']]).replace(0,np.inf)) - row['d'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
   a   b  c  d  dd  min_dd
0  0  15  0  8   6     2.0   # min_without_zero : 8 , dd : 6 -> 8-6=2 
1  2   0  5  3   2     0.0   # min_without_zero : 2 , dd : 2 -> 2-2=0
2  5   3  3  0   2     1.0   # 3 - 2
3  0   2  3  4   2     0.0   # 2 - 2
```

Answer (score 2):

*need to ignore 0 in rows*

Then just replace it with `nan`, consider following simple example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,0],"B":[3,5,7],"C":[7,0,7]})
df.replace(0,np.nan).apply(min)
df["minvalue"] = df.replace(0,np.nan).apply("min",axis=1)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
   A  B  C  minvalue
0  1  3  7       1.0
1  2  5  0       2.0
2  0  7  7       7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
cols = ['a','b','c','d']

df['res'] = df[cols][df[cols].ne(0)].min(axis=1) - df['dd']
```

```
print(df)

   a   b  c  d  dd  res
0  0  15  0  8   6  2.0
1  2   0  5  3   2  0.0
2  5   3  3  0   2  1.0
3  2   3  4  4   2  0.0
```